# How to find best datacenter in China?

Tags: datacenter, networking, colocation, physical-environment

I guess this question would be applicable for most countries but in this case, more specifically: if you do not speak Chinese how to find top tier data centers in China?

Comment: . . . Find someone who speaks Chinese? Ideally someone with a technical background?

Comment: YOU hire someone who can. Damn, what do you guys learn in school? go around and wait for other people to do your homework?

Answer (score 4):

My comment was pretty much the serious (and best I can come up with) answer to this question:

> Find yourself someone who speaks the both your language and the local language fluently -- ideally that person will have a technical background so they can speak intelligently about the topics at hand and things won't get too badly mangled in the translation.

---

If this is not practical, consider the following:

- Netcraft or other uptime monitoring services for sites they host
- Who they peer with (there are a few services online that take an IP or ASN and show you the neighbors)
- How well organized/designed their facility is

  - Proper hot/cold aisle layout. Bonus points for containment
  - Adequate (N+1 or better) cooling
  - Adequate UPS & Generator capacity
- Special Requirements -- things you may need that aren't "typical", like:

  - POTS lines
  - Off-Site tape rotation
- Whether there is staff on-site fluent in *your* language
  (It doesn't help if your site is down and you can't communicate with their staff!)

Answer (score 3):

Use a data center that has a [global presence](http://www.equinix.com/en_US/locations/china/china-data-centers/)... For example, [Equinix](http://www.equinix.com/en_US/locations/) has facilities everywhere I've needed connectivity or presence.

I've had application systems co-located in Hong Kong, Singapore, Tokyo, etc. Communication was never an issue.

Otherwise, many [opinions and experiences available on this forum](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?f=44).

Comment: If Hong Kong is "China" enough for you (and it is for most companies) there are many excellent global providers in that city - it would certainly help with narrowing your selection.

Answer (score 1):

Check with ChinaCache. They specialize on setting up an in-China presence for Western companies.